# Why does .length always return 0 in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to check if a div exist or not for the purpose that someone might get the result or not.

If the user get the result then class display_box will exist.

So I am using .length to check the class display_box exist or not; however, I have test that it always return 0 no matter there was a class or not.

I try to use ID.

I tried to use $myDiv.html().length

I tried .text(), .content().

I had tried .is(:empty) too. Is that because ajax, so basically, it will consider the class is not existed at all?

```js
ajax_search_load();//this is function to load my ajax 


  var $myDiv = $('.display_box');

      if ( $myDiv.length==0){
    alert('fsdfa');
      }
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous!

Comment: Try to do all your stuff once ajax call has been done in a promise way for example. `$.ajax({ ... }).then(function() { // check length });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Vohuman said, if you are making an asynchronous call, then execute your function in the callback of your ajax request, [example](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'foo.bar',
    type: 'GET',
    success : function (data) {
        //show your data
        $('#some-container').html(data);

        //find your div
        var $myDiv = $('#some-container').find('.display_box');

        //do some stuff
        if ( $myDiv.length==0){
            alert('fsdfa');
        }
    }
})
```